# Vimperator: How to press on buttons which aren't really links

Tags: vimperator

I know that I can open links by pressing f/F and then the number of the link.

But my problem is, that I am on a webpage with buttons, which do some stuff but they are no links. But I need to press them. How can I do this with Vimperator?

Thanks!

Comment: Many people (not just vimperator users) feel your pain on this... Placing links in Javascript / hover activated elements breaks sites for people that aren't using point and click devices to navigate the web.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the problem, but the issue may be circumvented with `:set usermode` in some cases (`:se um` for short). This lets you view the page with minimal CSS and reduces it to HTML elements that you can interact with via vimperator.

In the case of a page like http://stackexchange.com/sites, `:se um` will allow you to follow links to the sites directly. Depending on the site you are having the problem with, this may or may not help you.

Usermode can be disabled with `:se noum`.

Comment: While it doesn't solve the problem in the specific way that the OP requested, I thought that it would be useful to put it out there as an alternative for people with the same issue. Perhaps I phrased it poorly; this is my solution to getting past non link buttons on the websites I frequent, but I wouldn't date guarantee that this will work for every website. Apologies if answers like this aren't allowed as I'm a bit new.

Answer (score 1):

If buttons have text you should be able to find the text and press enter, which executes the button. Just tested this on this site:

[image: greyed out Vimperator is NOT highlighted if you use hints, so not a link, but it is a button]

On the right side of the picture, you have a tag. It's a button. It's greyed out, since I moved to it. Pressing Enter works, hints do not, it's NOT highlighted if you use them.

In other words, type `/vimperator` and then hit enter twice.  To do the same on this webpage itself, you could type `/Newbie` and hit enter twice, to visit the OP's webpage.